# How can I map over object values using Ramda.js and take only first element?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have input like that:

```
{
  a: [obj1, obj2, obj3...],
  b: [obj1, obj2, obj3...],
  c: [obj1, obj2, obj3...]
}
```

I want to have that output (only first object from array for every key)

```
{
  a: [obj1],
  b: [obj1],
  c: [obj1]
}
```

I want to do it using [ramda.js](http://ramdajs.com/docs/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest answer is just `map(head, obj)`, or if you want a reusable function, `map(head)`.

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?const%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20a%3A%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%0A%20%20b%3A%20%5B4%2C%205%2C%206%5D%2C%0A%20%20c%3A%20%5B7%2C%208%2C%209%5D%0A%7D%0A%0Amap%28head%2C%20obj%29)**.

Comment: Yes, that is much better! Simpler and more elegant! I was trying to use head, but not in exactly right way before.

Answer (score 4):

```
const data = {
  a: [obj1, obj2, obj3],
  b: [obj1, obj2, obj3],
  b: [obj1, obj2, obj3]
}

const updatedData = R.mapObjIndexed( value => ([value[0]]), data)
```

(This exact code won't work because `obj1`, `obj2`, and `obj3` aren't defined)

Comment: Note that since `key` is not used, you could simplify this to `R.map(value => value[0], data)`.  (Ramda treats Objects as functors that it knows how to map.)  But Ramda's `head` is essentially `xs => xs[0]`, so this could also be written as `R.map(R.head, data)`, and we arrive at my solution.